# Bad magic number in super-block: dm-crypt device

Tags: fsck, dm-crypt, superblock

I have a device that is encrypted using dm-crypt. This is a mini SD card that I use on my laptop.

I've had some issues with my laptop freezing recently, and in the journal these messages come up:

```
Mar 20 17:18:30 gorgonzola kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-0): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
Mar 20 17:18:30 gorgonzola kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-0): recovery complete
Mar 20 17:18:30 gorgonzola kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
...
Mar 20 17:23:30 gorgonzola kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-0): error count since last fsck: 84
Mar 20 17:23:30 gorgonzola kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-0): initial error at time 1505289981: ext4_journal_check_start:60
Mar 20 17:23:30 gorgonzola kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-0): last error at time 1551543757: ext4_reserve_inode_write:5903: inode 1054920: block 4194732
```

I have tried running fsck, but I get this error:

```
Bad magic number in super-block
```

Before attempting to resolve this, I just want to make sure that I should indeed be able to run fsck on a dm-encrypted drive. Or is this error expected? The reason why I am mystified is because I can mount this device just fine. For all intents and purposes, the drive works well. It mounts, it can read and write all data... the only problem is that I get this error at boot. So is there really a problem with the super block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to run `fsck` on the `/dev/sd*` (or whatever) device that refers to the actual SD or its partition, just like on an unencrypted device?

If so, that device is fully encrypted, and that's why `fsck` cannot make any sense of it at all. If it found anything recognizable as a filesystem, that would be a sign of `dm-crypt` not working: the encrypted data is supposed to look like nondescript pseudorandom noise.

You need to point the `fsck` to the `dm-crypt` target, which will probably be named `/dev/mapper/<something>`. And that requires using `cryptsetup` to open the encrypted device first, just like when preparing to mount the encrypted device, before trying to run `fsck` on it. Since `dm-crypt` has several possible modes, I cannot suggest a correct `cryptsetup` command without knowing more about your setup. Perhaps your `/etc/crypttab` file might contain the necessary details?